# Delete every 5th element in an array, but starting at 2nd element

Tags: javascript, arrays

My array is a sequence of 3 groups containing 5 elements.

```
var tempArray1 = ['prodn', 'PP1', 'UK1', 'Exp', 'India2', 'prodn', 'PP2', 'france1', 'Imp', 'Czech2', 'prodn', 'PP3', 'Germ1', 'Exp', 'Rom2']
```

I need to delete the 2nd element in my my array, and then delete every 5th element.  This will remove all elements starting with "PP".  Note that I want to delete with reference to position in array, not by character type.  The following is my code to remove every 5th element.

```
var indexToRemove = 5;  // start position
var numberToRemove = 1; // elements to remove

tempArray1.splice(indexToRemove, numberToRemove);
```

But how can I start this from the 2nd element?  Thank you.

Comment: Your code needs just one-liner, no need for these obsolete solutions in answers `tempArray1 = tempArray1.map((e,i)=> i === i*5+1 ? false : true)`

Comment: I know I messed up at the start by calling this jquery instead of javascript (qickly corrected) but why the 2nd downvote?,

Comment: Downvote removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `splice` you mutate the array (in-place), so you need to take steps of 4 instead of 5 as you already removed one value. Start a `for` loop at index 1:

```js
const tempArray1 = ['prodn', 'PP1', 'UK1', 'Exp', 'India2', 'prodn', 'PP2', 'france1', 'Imp', 'Czech2', 'prodn', 'PP3', 'Germ1', 'Exp', 'Rom2'];

for (let i = 1; i < tempArray1.length; i += 4) {
    tempArray1.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(tempArray1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var tempArray1 = ['prodn', 'PP1', 'UK1', 'Exp', 'India2', 'prodn', 'PP2', 'france1', 'Imp', 'Czech2', 'prodn', 'PP3', 'Germ1', 'Exp', 'Rom2']
    for(i=2-1; i< tempArray1.lenght; i+=5-1){
        // start with 2nd element (-1 because arrays start at 0)
        // and than jump to 5th element (-1 because the one has just been removed)
        // remove 1 element at i-th place 
        tempArray1.splice(i,1);
    }
```

Comment: Make that into a snippet with a test case.

Comment: Good that you corrected the step from 5 to 4, but you should also avoid that `i` is an implicitly declared global variable.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tempArray1 = ['prodn', 'PP1', 'UK1', 'Exp', 'India2', 'prodn', 'PP2', 'france1', 'Imp', 'Czech2', 'prodn', 'PP3', 'Germ1', 'Exp', 'Rom2'];

const newArray = tempArray1.filter(function(element, i){
    return (i % 5) != 1;
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: You don't need `i === 1` as a separate case, and you can move the 1 to the right side of the equation: `return i % 5 !== 1;` will do.